# You do/you are doing, you tell/you are telling me

Tags: present-tense

This is from my book "Longman English Grammar Practice" by L.G. Alexander.

Do "are doing/do", "you are telling me/you tell me" all sound natural and can I use "I am doubting"?

"Dear Jane,

Sorry to hear about your problem at work. I think you are doing/you do the right thing, but I doubt your boss really knows his job from what you are telling me/tell me."

Comment: It's always the continuous verb form in idiomatic emphatic agreement ***You're telling me**!* (with either or both of the senses ***I already know that**!* and/or ***I completely agree**!*). The non-continuous ***You tell me**!* is a completely different idiomatic usage meaning ***I have no idea** [what the answer is]. **Do you know**?* (often with the strong implication ***I doubt if you know either***).

Comment: Native Anglophones would rarely utter the sequence ***I am doubting***. That's a characteristic of "Indian English" which is usually seen as an error by native mainstream English speakers.

Comment: Is either do/doing acceptable? And tell/are telling me" in the original sentences?

Comment: _I think you do the right thing_ is not idiomatic in this context, but _tell/are telling_ would both be acceptable.

Comment: Is "do" wrong because from the  context it's obvious that she is doing that in the current situation which may be temporary and we are not talking about what she usually does in such situations. But with "tell/telling" it can a repeated action something she often tells her friend or again a temporary action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, "I am doubting" would be very rare and you'd best avoid it. However, I can think of one or two scenarios a native speaker might use such a construction.

1. "At first, I believed what he said. But right now, at this stage of the investigation, I am doubting this piece of evidence."
2. "Are you saying he's a liar?" "No, I'm doubting his behaviour."

It's probably because "doubting" belongs to a certain class of verbs about mental processes. So, for example, you've probably come across the phrase "Knowing him/her/etc", but you'd never hear a native speaker say "I am knowing...".